# parameterized remote trigger for multiple parallel calls

Tags: jenkins, build

I am not sure whats the best way to implement multiple parallel calls in Jenkins remotely.. Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

How to get the build number for  the multiple parallel calls (2-10 multiple calls) to the Jenkins Server for a parameteried job if it gets triggered remotely. One requirement is there will be no change in the build parameter. The development team is using  tool/python program to invoke 50 POST calls in that case how do we track the build number.

1. Scenario --  I have a freestyle parameterized job with Enable concurrent build  if necessary  box checked  for this job Sequential call for with same build parameters request when initiated remotely, we see  build number using https://jenkinsurl/queue/item with filtering out the  build number and then https://jenkins url/build/Consoletext -- This works
2. Scenario 2 -- Same request with no change with parameters when triggered multiple times more than 2 calls we can see the build number /Consoletext for the first call and later ones were unable to track with the build number.

Comment: Please ask your question in a single sentence. I get what you’re doing but don’t understand what you’re asking. Do you mean concurrent instead of parallel? Parallel is a different thing. Basically you’re asking you want to trigger a job remotely 50 times and store the build number somewhere?  Why not just get the most recent build number and subtract it by the number of calls our made?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner and trying to implement multiple parallel calls . My requirement is we have a python script that will return success and view other response which the dev Team needs as it contains a job id that get inserted into DB.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I am a beginner and trying to implement multiple parallel calls. My Jenkins job is configured to run a python script on the Jenkins server that will return success along with work id and other responses that the dev Team needs for further processing.
When the team triggers API remotely 50 times, only for the first call we see the build number/full response from the ConsoleText for the rest of the calls we don't see any build number. I don't see any failures also in Jenkins.  FYI   This is a free-style parameterized job concurrent build option enabled.